# Python Tkinter calling methods from a class in another file, and refreshing canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a simple state game with `Tkinter` using Canvas. 
When the user clicks the button getIn the value of man is supposed to change, however, it doesn't. I've tried to use the `self.canvas.update_idletasks`, but I'm not quite sure how to make that work either. 
Here's the function that's supposed to run when the user clicks "getIn":

```
def manGetIn():
    man = w.create_oval(350, 250, 205, 210, fill="black")
    w.Canvas.update_idletasks
    #Hvilken side er båten på? Fuark.
```

Here's the GUI of the relevant GUI of the game

```
    from Tkinter import *
    from tape import * #The module with methods I want to call in the game



class RiverCrossing:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.tape = Database()



        master.title("River Crossing")
        w = Canvas(master, width=900, height=900)
        w.pack()

        w.create_rectangle(200, 900, 750, 0,  fill="blue")
        w.create_rectangle(200, 900, 0, 0, fill="green")
        w.create_rectangle(900, 0, 750, 800, fill="green")
        #Lager landskapet(water, left, right)

        global boat 
        boat = w.create_rectangle(400, 300, 201, 200, fill="brown") 
        global chicken
        chicken = w.create_oval(150, 180, 180, 200, fill="yellow") 
        global grain 
        grain = w.create_oval(130, 180, 160, 170, fill="white") 
        global man 
        man = w.create_oval(150, 250, 180, 200, fill="black") 
        global fox 
        fox = w.create_oval(100, 130, 180, 150, fill="orange")  



        bottomFrame = Frame(master)
        bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        getIn = Button(bottomFrame, text="Get in boat", bg="white", fg="black", command= lambda: Database.manGetIn)

        crossRiver = Button(bottomFrame, text="Cross River", bg="black", fg="white", command= lambda: Database.set_boat(new_pos)) 



        getIn.grid(row=0)
        crossRiver.grid(row=2, column=2)



root = Tk()
rc = RiverCrossing(root)
root.mainloop()
```

When I test the game and call the `riverCrossing` function(from *tape.py* module), I get the error

> global new_pos not defined.

```
  def set_boat(self, new_pos):
    if new_pos in ('left','right'):
        self.boat = new_pos
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: please show the full, exact error. Like the error says, `new_pos` isn't defined, yet you're trying to pass it in your button command. What do you think `new_pos` is supposed to be? Also, there's no point in a `return` statement in a function called by a button -- the return value is simply ignored.

Comment: new_pos is a parameter in set_boat in another file I'm trying to call in RiverCrossing class.